# borrar cadena a la derecha C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

como puedo hacer un borrado hacia la derecha a partir de una palabra?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cfdi:Comprobante xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/3/cfdv33.xsd" Version="3.3"
 Folio="8" Fecha="2021-04-08T00:00:00" SubTotal="0.00" TipoCambio="16.2000" Moneda="MXN" Total="0.00" TipoDeComprobante="T" LugarExpedicion="97196" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3"><cfdi:Emisor RegimenFiscal="601" 
 Rfc="XIA190128J61" Nombre="Emisor Pruebas" /><cfdi:Receptor Rfc="AID031212SN4" Nombre="Combustibles de Chazumba" UsoCFDI="G01" /><cfdi:Conceptos>
 <cfdi:Concepto Cantidad="500" ClaveUnidad="31" Unidad="Pescar" ClaveProdServ="10101502" Descripcion="Perros" ValorUnitario="0.01" Importe="5.00" />
 </cfdi:Conceptos></cfdi:Comprobante> 
 |&acuse|Acuse disponible solo en el gestor JVBERi0xLj QKJeLjz9MKMSAwIG9iago8PC9Db2xvclNwYWNlL0RldmljZVJHQi9TdWJ0eXBlL0ltYWdlL0hlaWdodCA3OS9GaWx0ZXIvRENURGVjb2RlL1R5cGUvWE9iamVjdC9XaWR0aCAyMTIvQml0c1BlckNvbXB
```

</cfdi:Comprobante>  quiero borrar todo hacia la derecha a partir de esta palabra.

intente este código, le quito algunas cadenas al principio por eso es la primera parte , pero al final no siempre tienen la misma longitud, varia la respuesta.

```
 result = result.Substring(39,result.legth - 18 );
```

el result es donde guardo mi cadena.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes realizarlo de esta forma calculando la posición de la palabra y eliminando a partir de ese punto los caracteres siguientes, no debes usar valores fijos, debes calcularlos:

```
string delafteWord = "</cfdi:Comprobante>";
string input = "<cfdi:Comprobante xsi:schemaLocation=\"http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/3/cfdv33.xsd\" Version=\"3.3\" Folio=\"8\" Fecha=\"2021-04-08T00:00:00\" SubTotal=\"0.00\" TipoCambio=\"16.2000\" Moneda=\"MXN\" Total=\"0.00\" TipoDeComprobante=\"T\" LugarExpedicion=\"97196\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:cfdi=\"http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3\"><cfdi:Emisor RegimenFiscal=\"601\" Rfc=\"XIA190128J61\" Nombre=\"Emisor Pruebas\" /><cfdi:Receptor Rfc=\"AID031212SN4\" Nombre=\"Combustibles de Chazumba\" UsoCFDI=\"G01\" />cfdi:Conceptos <cfdi:Concepto Cantidad=\"500\" ClaveUnidad=\"31\" Unidad=\"Pescar\" ClaveProdServ=\"10101502\" Descripcion=\"Perros\" ValorUnitario=\"0.01\" Importe=\"5.00\" /> </cfdi:Conceptos></cfdi:Comprobante> |&acuse|Acuse disponible solo en el gestor JVBERi0xLj QKJeLjz9MKMSAwIG9iago8PC9Db2xvclNwYWNlL0RldmljZVJHQi9TdWJ0eXBlL0ltYWdlL0hlaWdodCA3OS9GaWx0ZXIvRENURGVjb2RlL1R5cGUvWE9iamVjdC9XaWR0aCAyMTIvQml0c1BlckNvbXB";


int start = input.LastIndexOf(delafteWord) + delafteWord.Length;            
string result = input.Remove(start, input.Length - start);
```

por lo tanto obtendrías como salida el valor de `result` :

`<cfdi:Comprobante xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/3/cfdv33.xsd" Version="3.3" Folio="8" Fecha="2021-04-08T00:00:00" SubTotal="0.00" TipoCambio="16.2000" Moneda="MXN" Total="0.00" TipoDeComprobante="T" LugarExpedicion="97196" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3"><cfdi:Emisor RegimenFiscal="601" Rfc="XIA190128J61" Nombre="Emisor Pruebas" /><cfdi:Receptor Rfc="AID031212SN4" Nombre="Combustibles de Chazumba" UsoCFDI="G01" />cfdi:Conceptos <cfdi:Concepto Cantidad="500" ClaveUnidad="31" Unidad="Pescar" ClaveProdServ="10101502" Descripcion="Perros" ValorUnitario="0.01" Importe="5.00" /> </cfdi:Conceptos></cfdi:Comprobante>`

Comment: gracias JORGE me funciono de maravilla.

Comment: Excelente @DavidCabrera , saludos!